# How to localize special ressource types like sounds, images, movies, html files and so on?

Tags: iphone, ipad, localization, internationalization

I know I can use NSLocalizeableString() for strings. But how about about other kinds of resources? I guess there are some kind of language folders where I put that into? Is there an good blog article that describes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on any file and choose `Get Info`. In the General Tab of the InfoView hit the `Make File Localizable` button, and add a localization. Xcode will copy this file to a location-specific folder in your project.

I use Finder to copy my language specific files into those folders.

Comment: Sounds great. And then iOS will automatically pick the right one based on the current language?